# List Enterprise Keywords in a Content Search WebPart Display Template

Tags: 2013, search, search-results, display-template, content-search-web-part

I am having problems preparing my own display template for the Content By Search WebPart running queries on a wiki page library - so far I have been successfull in displaying the title, author and the decoded html preview of the wiki page item, however I cannot seem to find a way to display the Enterprise Keywords.

I would like to show them as a comma-separated text line, i.e.

> Keywords: keyword1, keyword2, keyword3

If I understand it correctly, I should get the Managed Metadata Property name:
[image: Keywords]
...and add it to the display template, the same way I add other properties:

```
<mso:ManagedPropertyMapping msdt:dt="string">'Picture URL'{Picture URL}:'PublishingImage;PictureURL;PictureThumbnailURL','Link URL'{Link URL}:'Path','Line 1'{Line 1}:'Title','Line 2'{Line 2}:'Author','Line 3'{Line 3}:'WikiFieldOWSMTXT','SecondaryFileExtension','ContentTypeId'</mso:ManagedPropertyMapping>
```

In my case I'd like to display it instead of displaying the Author (which displays fine), however that just causes SharePoint to display nothing in that place. I realise I have to do something else on the property to have it displayed like I want to but have no idea what.

Here's how the html part looks like, which works fine for Author but not Keywords:

```
<div class="cbs-picture3LinesLine2 ms-noWrap" title="_#= $htmlEncode(line2.defaultValueRenderer(line2)) =#_" id="_#= line2Id =#_" > Author: _#= line2 =#_</div>
```

Please advise.

Edit* After attaching a console.log(line2) command to the javascript part, I get a property which is already empty, according to SharePoint:
[image: chrome's console log]
What could be the reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, turns out I was using the wrong managed property - the actual property responsible for the enterprise keyword was called Tags:
[image: Tags]
Have to be more careful next time.

Edit==> No, tags returns keywords and managed properties ! you can test that by adding a new managed property and the result will be combined between keywords and that property !